# Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device)

Tags: macos, docker, debian, apt, apt-get

How to resolve the error when I run the apt-get update command? I have more than 100 GB left on my mac device

```
 Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device)
```

Commands that I executed to check the free space.

```
user:~/.docker$df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   233Gi   93Gi  136Gi    41% 1479561 9223372036853296246    0%   /
devfs          187Ki  187Ki    0Bi   100%     648                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4   233Gi  4.0Gi  136Gi     3%       4 9223372036854775803    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /home

user:~/.docker$cat daemon.json 
{
  "debug" : true,
  "experimental" : false
}

user:~/.docker$cat config.json 
{
  "credsStore" : "desktop",
  "auths" : {

  },
  "stackOrchestrator" : "swarm",
  "experimental" : "disabled"
}
```

Comment: can you show us the disk usage? just in case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured the local environment docker to reuse the docker daemon inside the minikube instance.

There were many docker images listed when I used `docker images` command

Removed all the docker images using `docker rmi -f imageName`

After removing all the docker images, I was able to get some space and the Debian issue is resolved